# Criando um App para Sharepoint usando Dev, AngularJS e RestAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

Estou precisando criar um app para o sharepoint que faz a simples tarefa de listar campos de uma lista na tela onde o App for colocado dentro do Sharepoint.

Estou com o seguinte erro:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Esse código está dentro do default.aspx criado pelo Napa:

```
<div ng-app>
    <b>Lista simples AngularJS + Sharepoint!</b>
    <div ng-controller="MyController" class="ng-scope">
        <div ng-repeat="p in Products">
            Product Name: {{p.ProductName}} <br />
            Rate: Rs. {{p.ProductRate}} <br />
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>    
    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.loadREST = function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductList')/items?$select=ProductName,ProductRate",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSONP",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var newData = [];
                    jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
                        newData.push({ ProductName: value.ProductName, ProductRate: value.ProductRate});
                    });
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.Products = newData;
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    //alert(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
                    alert("erro de conexão");
                }
            });
        };
        $scope.loadREST();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Esse erro que você relata é típico de requisição ajax sendo negada porque você está tentado acessar outro domínio. Se você pegar o valor de `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` no console, dá o mesmo domínio que você está usando na barra de endereço?

Answer (score 3):

Use `dataType: "JSONP"` na sua chamada ajax! Isso irá incluir o header necessário para requisições cross domain. Importante frisar que você deve usar uma versão da jQuery superior à 1.7

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54212/discussion-on-answer-by-tiago-cesar-oliveira-criando-um-app-para-sharepoint-usan)